# Classpath entry eclipse.fproj.jdt.libprov.osgi/jpt.jpa is marked for publish/export but is not exported on the project classpath

Tags: eclipse, jpa, glassfish, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

I'm trying to get a new Enterprise Application Project set up in Eclipse using Glassfish as my app server and I'm seeing the following warning:

Classpath entry eclipse.fproj.jdt.libprov.osgi/jpt.jpa is marked for publish/export but is not exported on the project classpath. Classpath visibility within Eclipse and at runtime will differ.

I've got the Java Persistence 1.0 facet enabled on my EJB project and I'm pretty sure this is what's causing my problems. I've done a lot of searching, but to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it. I had it marked as a Java EE module dependency, but I didn't have it selected for export. In the project properties window I went to Java Build Path > Order and Export and placed a check next to the entry for EclipseLink 1.1.x.

Comment: After changing the "Order and Export" settings I also had to do "Project > Clean..." to make the warning go away.